# Javascript chart example

Tags: eclipse-scout

I saw charts in BSI CRM, and they look awesome. I tried to find online tutorial about making own widgets, everyone reported to look at heatmap example code, but it is confusing. Where to start?

But I would like to see a tutorial to show simple chart or any other javascript widget in scout. I need steps where to start..

Is there any tutorial, can someone write it. Only in few lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use charts in a Scout application you have to choose a chart library and include it into your project. I’ll give you an example with [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/). For you it is probably easiest to look at the commit (link below) to do the same in your project. I’ll write a short cheat sheet on ‘How to integrate ChartJS in Scout applications’ within the next days and link it as soon as it is available.

Depending on what you are using, ScoutJS (JavaScript only) or Scout Classic (Java based application model), the integration of external libraries differs.

ScoutJS:
[Commit: 'Added ChartJS example to JSWidgets app.'](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs/commit/15a4e3270dd06219a284f2e9fa59e6c001c71cd4)

Scout Classic:
[Commit: 'ChartJS example for classic widget app.'](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs/commit/baba93e3b8eb3271be82aa66eb2ac187e34ed882)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Please don't answer off topic questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer